# Skaffold: missing resource metadata on Redis in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, redis, skaffold

I am using skaffold for my kubernetes local cluster deployment. Currently, I am trying to setup Redis. So far, I have written a "token-redis.yaml" file that contains the configmap, pvc, pv, statefulset and clusterip service. When I save the changes, skaffold gives me the following error:

**"Skipping render due to error:missing Resource metadata"**

This is my YAML file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: token-redis-configmap
data:
  update-node.sh: |
    #!/bin/sh
    REDIS_NODES="/data/nodes.conf"
    sed -i -e "/myself/ s/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/${POD_IP}/" ${REDIS_NODES}
    exec "$@"
  redis.conf: |+
    cluster-enabled yes
    cluster-require-full-coverage no
    cluster-node-timeout 15000
    cluster-config-file /data/nodes.conf
    cluster-migration-barrier 1
    appendonly yes
    protected-mode no
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: redis-pv-01
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /redis01
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: token-redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: token-redis
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: token-redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: token-redis
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: conf
          configMap:
            name: "token-redis-configmap"
            defaultMode: 0755
      containers:
        - name: token-redis-container
          image: redis:5.0.1-alpine
          command: ["/conf/update-node.sh", "redis-server", "/conf/redis.conf"]
          env:
            - name: POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: "status.podIP"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
              name: client
            - containerPort: 16379
              name: gossip
          volumeMounts:
            - name: conf
              mountPath: "/conf"
              readOnly: false
            - name: data
              mountPath: "/data"
              readOnly: false
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: token-redis-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: token-redis
  ports:
    - name: client
      port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
    - name: gossip
      port: 16379
      targetPort: 16379
```